# Analyzing fluctuations within the Signal

Tags: signal-analysis, stochastic, random-process

I am trying to figure out how to analyze the signal shown below. It shows the fluctuation of number of review in for a product in Amazon, where positive means addition number of review while negative means deleted number of reviews.

Is there any way to extract trend from such signal? For example, the trend of deleted review is consistent etc.

I am new in signal processing so I am not really sure what technique I can use.

[image: Fluctuation of number of review]

Comment: Can you please add a little bit more information regarding your graph? What is the horizontal axis of your graph for example (?)

Comment: x-axis is the hour while y-axis is the changes of the number of reviews. For example, in t hour, the number increase by 1. Negative value (e.x. -2) represents decrease of the number of reviews.

Comment: Is $x$ a timestamp? In other words, is $x$ continuous or do you simply have the timestamp at which a given change took place?

Comment: yes, there is a timestamp for x. the interval between x and x+1 is 1 hour. However, it is not exactly continuous due to some missing data (not tracked at certain point).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you have in your graph is the [first derivative](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Derivative) of your number of reviews with respect to time.

In order to study any trends to the number of reviews itself, you will first have to [integrate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integration) your derivative.

At its simplest form, this could be achieved by starting with an initial value for number of reviews ($nReviews$) and then iterating over each time point ($n$) of your derivative signal ($dReviews$), adding or subtracting the amount of reviews. That is, given $nReviews_0=N$ then $nReviews_{n+1} = nReviews_n + D_n$ where $n$ is your index that varies between 0 and number of hour measurements (assuming that $x$ is **continuous**). If you don't have $N$ you can simply start with 0. In fact, if you are just interested in discovering a trend, you can safely assume $N=0$.

Once you get your $nReviews$ signal you can have a look at its mean and standard deviation as the bear minimum for estimating a trend. A mean that is greater than zero means there is an increasing trend, a mean below zero means that there is a decreasing trend and finally something close to zero would mean no change. How far away from zero a trend has to be (standard deviation) to be considered "large" or "small" depends on your dataset (that is, other "review signals").

Another thing you can do is try to [fit a low order polynomial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curve_fitting#Different_types_of_curve_fitting) and see how much of your data variation it can explain. At its simplest form, you can fit a line through the data and examine its slope (which is equivalent to deriving a mean over the time window you have data for).

Finally, if you wanted to estimate an average $nReviews$ over, for example, 6hr, 12hr, 24hr, 7*24hr, 30*24hr and so on then you can create a simple [moving average filter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moving_average) and apply it to the $nReviews$ time series. The signal at the output of that filter is your hourly, daily, weekly, monthly and so on, average of $nReviews$.

**BUT**, if your axis $x$ is a timestamp, then this means that there might be different time intervals that have passed between any $n$, $n+1$ in $D_n$. In that case, you will have to first interpolate $D$ so that the measurements are put in exactly the right time instants  and then proceed as above.

Hope this helps.

Comment: even though the x-axis is a timestamp, I can still adopt what you are suggesting as the interval between one timestamp and another is fixed. Will try. Thanks. :)

Comment: Thank you for letting me know, if you found the post useful, you can upvote or accept this response.